# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
#include <unistd.h>
void    ft_print_alphabet(void)
{
    write(1, 
 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 26);
}
```

I tried running the above in VS Code and I got the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_main", referenced from:
>
> implicit entry/start for main executable
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a **main function** as C expects one, and then you can call your function from `main()`:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

void ft_print_alphabet(void)
{
    write(1, 
 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 26);
}

int main() {
    ft_print_alphabet();
    return 0;
}
```